# AMP Pages Tags Show’s on Desktop Google Search?

Tags: amp-html

Iam Using AMP plugin on my WordPress Website ,
Today i detected some of tags are indexed in Normal Google Search [Desktop] .

iam searching my website like[ search as “site:sitename.com” ] . i got some google search results like **www.example.com/tag/pune/?amp** , Here tag is "**pune**" , but i disallowed indexing of tags on Search Engines via Sitemap.

i think Due to this, My Website Will penalized by Google Search in Future .
How to Solve This Problem

Answer (score 1):

if there is canonical link, then it wont be treated as 2 different pages.

Comment: I think it would help if you went more into detail on what a canonical link is, how to implement it and why this solves the problem. (Just use links to existing pages, if you wish)

Answer (score 1):

You may check this blog: [How To Remove Indexed WordPress Categories, Tags, & Attachment Links From Google](http://www.shoutmeloud.com/how-to-deindex-wordpress-tags-categories-attachment-google.html). Since you're using WordPress, make sure that your [Robots.txt](http://www.shoutmeloud.com/what-is-robots-txt-file-and-how-to-optimize-for-wordpress-blogs.html) is not blocking access to the tags and categories pages. If a few of your pages are already indexed in Google and you have added the noindex tag, Google may have stopped crawling of that part of your site and never see the noindex tag because `Robots.txt` is blocking access to crawlers.

Check what pages of your site is indexed in Google by typing this search operator into Google: `site:domain.com (replace domain.com with your domain)`. Read the blog for the complete instructions.

You might also check this [article](https://perishablepress.com/tell-google-to-not-index-certain-parts-of-your-page/) on how Google will not index certain parts of your page.

- [Robots.txt directives](https://perishablepress.com/robots-notes-plus/)
- [Nofollow attributes on links](https://perishablepress.com/much-ado-about-nofollow-the-perishable-press-dofollow-series/)
- [Meta noindex/nofollow directives](https://perishablepress.com/xhtml-document-header-resource/)
- [X-Robots noindex/nofollow directives](https://perishablepress.com/taking-advantage-of-the-x-robots-tag/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: i agree with you , but i made this changes already[before amp plugin installation] , but after installing amp plugin i got this issue , [this is not normal tags problem , here www.example.com/tag/pune/?amp , Here amp aslo added, so iam expecting this problem due to amp . ] , if it is 10-50 google search results ok , i can remove it from google , but there are many number of links are indexed .